# R Calculating circulate in big data

Tags: arrays, r, calculated-columns

```
  k=seq(10100,249250621,10)

  a =data.frame(nrow=300000,ncol=5) #like this format:

  chr1 100000851 + 2 100000925

  chr1 100001273 + 3 100001347

..............................
```

1.Now I  want to calculate :

for every `a[i,5]` ,search the `k[j]` which could make `a[i,5]` in the interval

```
 (k[j]-75,k[j]+75)
```

then merge a `new data.frame(),make a[i,6]=k[j]`

2.I have write two codes,but I don't know where I am wrong:

```
1)

     b=function(x){

     x1=a[which(a[,5]-(x-75)>0&a[,5]-(x+75)<0,]

     x2=cbind(x1,x)

   }

   c=apply(k,1,function(x)a(x))

  2)

    for(i in 1:length(k)){

      if(length(N1<-which(a[,5]-(k-75)>0&a[,5]-(k+75)<0))>0){

        for(j in N1){

           x1=cbind(k,a[j,])

           x2=rbind(x2,x1)

        }

       }

      }
```

but both of them are wrong.

Any one who give advise could be very appreciate!

Comment: What happens if two or no "k"s match the condition? Could you give an example "a[, 5]" and "k" that take into account for any constraints? As a start, it seems that you could try something like `sapply(a[, 5], function(x) k[x >= (k - 75) & x <= (k + 75)])`?

Comment: Thank you. @ alexis_laz  # for example, there should be 'k' who can match the condition,if there are more than two k match this,then combine each of the k to construct the new data.frame().                        ' chr1 100000851 + 2 100000925  100000925(k)    '                       ' chr1 100000851 + 2 100000925  100000935(k)   '                     'chr1 100000851 + 2 100000925  100000945(k)'                          'chr1 100000851 + 2 100000925  100000955(k)'

Comment: Could you give me some advise?These have confused me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

From what I get from the comments, something like the following should be helpful:

```
#sample "a" and "k"
a = data.frame(col1 = paste("chr", rep(1:2, 2), sep = ""), col2 = sample(4),
               col3 = "+", col4 = 1:4, col5 = c(215, 502, 345, 1007))
a
k = c(200, 300, 400, 500, 800, 1000)

a[[6]] = sapply(a[[5]], function(x) 
                            paste(k[x >= (k - 75) & x <= (k + 75)], collapse = ", "))
a
#  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5       V6
#1 chr1    4    +    1  215      200
#2 chr2    2    +    2  502      500
#3 chr1    3    +    3  345 300, 400
#4 chr2    1    +    4 1007     1000
```

Comment: Wonderful!  Thank a lot. But could you tell me how can you think of trans 'a'(which is a data.frame) to a list? I means a[[6]],which is a list.As for me,what I thought 'a' was only a data.frame. Besides ,what remaind you of using 'paste' function to combine all the results  ?

Comment: @flybird: See `is.list(a)` and `unclass(a)`; "data.frame"s are a specially treated and formated type of a "list" with elements of equal length. So, `a[[5]]` and `a$col5` can be used; `a[, 5]` is a convenient "matrix-like" operator for "data.frame"s. `paste` is the most common function to combine elements into one; it differs from `c`/`rbind`/`cbind` in that it returns a character vector (sometimes that is not wanted/useful). Instead of `paste` you could have two columns of "k"s where "a[, 5]"s that have only one "k" would have a `NA` in the second column. It all comes down to specific needs.

Comment: Thank you !  @ alexis_laz. Now I know the the special character of  data.frame.But when I use the methods what you had told me ,the codes have ran over one day,until now  it didn't stop.So I  ceased it manually.What's happened to them?The ' k' was seq(10100,249250621,10).